# Stuck with Modal creation (Javascript and HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have just started working with Javascript and I am trying to implement a Modal. I have included a button through index.js to index.html but when I click the button (in the browser) it does not generate de modal. I dont know what I am doing wrong :-(. Any recommendation?

My codes are the following:
**"index.js"**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css'
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map'
import './assets/css/now-ui-kit.css'
import './assets/css/now-ui-kit.css.map'
import './assets/css/now-ui-kit.min.css'


const teste = (
<React.Fragment>
<div class="row" id="modals">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch Modal
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_simple-remove"></i>
          </button>
          <h4 class="title title-up">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.
         </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Nice Button</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(teste, document.getElementById('modalteste'));
```

---

**"index.html"**

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="./assets/css/now-ui-kit.css?v=1.3.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="header"></header><br>
  <div id="root"></div> <br>
  <div id="modalteste"></div> 
  

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any event-listeners. How would the browser know what to do when you press that button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. 
You need to define its state false. 
This example will work.

```
class EditBlog extends Component {
    state = {
        modal: false,


    }

    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newBlog = {

        this.toggle();
    }
    render(){
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;

        return(
            <span>

                <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={this.toggle} >
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <Modal 
                    isOpen = {this.state.modal}
                    toggle = {this.toggle}    
                ></Modal>

                <Modal 
                    isOpen = {this.state.modal}
                    toggle = {this.toggle}    
                >
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
                        Add to blog List
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Form onSubmit ={this.onSubmit }>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="blogHeading">Blog Heading</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_short_desc" id="blogHeading" placeholder="Add one liner"
                                onChange={this.onChange} value={this.props.blog_short_desc}/>
                                 <Label for="blogName">Blog Name</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_name" id="blogName" placeholder="Add blog name"
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                <Label for="desc1">Description </Label>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="blog_desc" id="desc1" placeholder="Add your blog"
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                 <Label for="imageUrl">Image Url</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_image_link" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Add image url (Optional)"
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>


                                <Button
                                    color="dark"
                                    style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
                                    block
                                >Edit blog</Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </span>
        )
    }
}


export default EditBlog;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.